# Android accessibility for TextView with different locales

Tags: android, localization, accessibility, talkback

In my app, I have android:text="@string/myText" set for a TextView. This myText is picked from strings.xml based on the localization(English/German). 
For English: SETTINGS
For German: EINSTELLUNGEN 
With TalkBack on, Android announces SETTINGS (locale is English) but it does not announce EINSTELLUNGEN (locale is German). 
What would be the reason ? 
 Does CAPITAL LETTERS of the text have anything to do with this ?
 Below is my TextView in the xml:

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/settings_text"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="48dp"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:text="@string/settings"
android:textColor="@color/st_white"
android:textStyle="bold"
android:textSize="15sp"/>
```

The "settings" string is present in two different strings.xml files for English(default) and German version.
English: values/strings.xml
`<string name="settings">SETTINGS</string>`
German: values-de/strings.xml 
`<string name="settings">EINSTELLUNGEN</string>`
I can see the display if "Display speech output" setting is turned on(TalkBack Settings -> Developer Settings) but could not hear the same.

Comment: Not enough information.  It could be far too many problems.  Are you localizing properly?  Did you grab onto the string properly?  How did you build your Settings button? Etc.  Of all the issues I can promise that it is not, it is not capitalization of the letters :).  We need more information, perhaps a code sample?

Comment: Wait, so the "Display Speech Output" is displaying the proper text, but the announcement is different?

Comment: @ChrisCM: "Display Speech Output" is displaying the proper text but the announcement does not say anything. :(

Comment: Be sure you have the proper TTS Engine installed: https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/androidtm-how-to/9780133802092/ch02lev2sec32.html

Comment: I am using Nexus 4 device which has inbuilt TalkBack feature. How to be sure that proper TTS engine is installed ?

Comment: @ChrisCM I have tested on Samsung S5 and **EINSTELLUNGEN** is announced there. I have verified with both Samsung TTS engine and Google TTS engine on Samsung S5. So this seems to be Nexus 4 specific issue. Your comments ?

Comment: I don't have a Nexus 4 to test on to confirm, but if everything you say is correct, it might be a bug.  I don't know if Nexus 4 is still in the support chain.  I have a Nexus 7 and 5, so I can't really help any more...

Comment: Updating the Talkback as mentioned in the answer, I am able to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been resolved by updating **Google Talkback** and **Google Text-to-Speech** from the Playstore. 
After updating both, I have to turn Talkback OFF (if already ON), change the device locale (in my case to Deutsch for German) and then turn ON Talkback. This will automatically download updates for the locale text-to-speech.